# gnuplot rotate axis label (xlabel, ylabel and zlabel) not working in 3d plots

Tags: rotation, gnuplot

I am having hard time aligning y-axis and z-axis labels with axis tics on my 3d plots. 
Here is my code.

```
  set ylabel "Infectious Duration (days)" rotate by 90
  set zlabel "Compute Time (sec)" rotate by 90
  set logscale x

  splot  "TCompISIS3d.txt" using 1:2:3 title 'SIS-Inf1' with points , \
         "TCompISIS3d.txt" using 1:4:5 title 'SIS-Inf4' with points , \
         "TCompISIS3d.txt" using 1:6:7 title 'SIS-Inf10' with points , \
         "TCompISIS3d.txt" using 1:8:9 title 'SIS-Inf50' with points
```

But it doesn't rotate any of the labels. Please Help!

Comment: Please read the docs: `The orientation (rotation angle) of the x, x2, y and y2 axis labels in 2D plots can be changed by specifying rotate by <degrees>. The orientation of the x and y axis labels in 3D plots defaults to horizontal but can be changed to run parallel to the axis by specifying rotate parallel.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting an arbitrary rotation of the axis labels with `rotate by` works only for 2D plots. In 3D you can only use `rotate parallel` to change the label orientation to run parallel to the respective axis. From the docs under `III Commands → Set-show → Xlabel`:

> The orientation (rotation angle) of the x, x2, y and y2 axis labels in 2D plots can be changed by specifying **rotate by** .  The orientation of the x and y axis labels in 3D plots defaults to horizontal but can be changed to run parallel to the axis by specifying
>   **rotate parallel**.